# php curl returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-400

Guys.

I wrote one script to get content from some links using proxy.
If you know the reason and have advise, please help me.
Thanks

When I run following code, then it displays 400 error code.

```
$linkCheck = "https://www.uwgc.org/give/donor-networks/step-up-program/2016/03/14/oh-the-places-she's-going";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linkCheck);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $workingProxy['port']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $workingProxy['ip']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $workingProxy['username'].':'.$workingProxy['password']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$error_report= curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($httpcode != 200){
        echo '<pre>' . $httpcode .'</pre>' ;
    return null;
}else{
    return $data;
}
```

Expected Behavior:

Getting correct content of given link.

Comment: Do you really have access to this URL?

Comment: You can use Postman first to check if the URL is giving the correct Response back.

Comment: @Akintunde-rotimi yeah, its url works well, you can visit it on your browser.

Comment: @manishk I checked its url using postman. It works well with status code 200.

Comment: What does a var_dump($data) give you right after $data = curl_exec($ch); ?
Does that dump help you out?

Comment: What is the full result of the $error_report variable?

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log.

Comment: 'HTTP' is not a valid proxy type, and CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE does not take strings, it takes integers. you need to check your curl_setopt return values, then you would have noticed this bug. the correct code should read: `if(!curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP)){throw new \RuntimeException("Failed to set CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE");}`

Comment: Hi, @everyone.
Thanks for your tips.